# COMP_LINE not set despite bash completion being installed

Tags: macos, bash, environment-variables, homebrew, tab-completion

I'm using homebrew's bash completion package on OSX, which is installed in /usr/local/etc/bash_completion. It's working fine, but there are many extensions for it which rely on various environment variables beginning with COMP_, such as COMP_LINE. These environment variables unfortunately aren't being exported into my bash environment, despite the fact that the proper files are being sourced. Here is the applicable area in my .bash_profile:

```
# bash completion
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
  . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi
```

Yet COMP_LINE isn't set, which is preventing other completion addons from working:

```
> env | grep COMP_LINE
>
```

Any ideas why the environment variables aren't set? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$COMP_LINE` is not an environment variable. It is an internal variable, and it's only visible to the completion functions, not to other shell usage. (Most other internal variables are visible in `declare`.)

Comment: I guess I'm confused because this script seems to be expecting that variable to be available in the environment and is not finding it:

https://github.com/xaviershay/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/rake-complete.rb

Comment: The script expects it, because it is normally invoked inside a completion handler (actually *as* a completion handler). I was wrong about the variable type, though -- it seems that `COMP_*` variables *are* being exported to the environment. I have tried the `rake-complete` script and it works...

Comment: Thanks, it appears the completion script was actually working but there was a bug in it that was skipping the first rake task in the list, which just happened to be the one I was trying to execute.